# onclick Javascript link is not supported in lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, popup, custom-link

I am just trying to open a popup window by clicking on custom link in my page layout and it seems working in salesforce classic but not in Lightning view.

What i have found is few people suggested to do as mentioned in trialhead section but i am unable to find out any way for custom links.

Can anyone help me to display a popup on click of custom link in lightning experience or suggest me the way that how can i achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> OnClick JavaScript buttons pose security and regulatory issues.
>   Lightning was built from the ground up to deliver the most secure
>   experience possible with technologies such as LockerService. We want
>   to ensure the continued integrity of this security model and as a
>   result will not be supporting OnClick JavaScript buttons in Lightning.
>   However to ease the transition Salesforce are constantly looking for
>   declarative and programmatic alternatives to help make this transition
>   from OnClick JavaScript buttons to Lightning Alternatives easier and
>   easier.

This table maps use cases for JavaScript buttons to alternate—and in most cases, better—solutions in Lightning.:-

[image]

> Also, On Trailblazer community we have a group called "Lightning Now!"
>   where experts can assist in this process

Refer below links for more Information :-

1. [Idea -Onclick Javascript Buttons with Lightning Experience](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cGX8AAM)
2. [Lightning Alternatives to JavaScript Buttons](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration)

The trailhead [Lightning Alternatives to JavaScript Buttons](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration) will give you some example and more detailed explanation. You can edit your question and include the Onclick JavaScript Link to get more help.